# Xcode quits when changing the content inset of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I am using Xcode 8.1. I drag a textfield into a UIViewController. In the size inspector panel in the storyboard, I change the layout margins to be explicitly set. As soon as I modify the the top, left, right, or bottom values, Xcode quits immediately. This occurs repeatedly. I can do it programmatically but since there is an option in the storyboard and also that I won't change these values, I felt it right to do in the storyboard. Is this an issue in the Xcode or am I missing something?

Comment: Force Quit or Shut Down your system and then check.. hope it will work.

Comment: Send a bug report to bugreport.apple.com

Comment: It crashes in xCode 8 too. It may be a bug in xCode.

Comment: its bug , am facing too